# Visual Basic - Auto Moving Pictures

Tags: vb6

I'm making an application where I need "enemies" to pace back and forth, how would I automatically move the picture from left to right and repeat?

Heres my current code.

```
Private Sub Timer1_Timer()
    enemy1.Left = enemy1.Left - 5
End Sub
```

Comment: The language being used is basic

Comment: No.  Are you using VB6 or VB.Net?

Comment: I posted an answer below that will hopefully be helpful.

Answer (score 1):

```
Option Explicit
Const nTwipsPerMove = 15
Private Sub Timer1_Timer()
    Static strDirection As String
    If strDirection = "" Then strDirection = "left"
    If enemy.Left > 0 Then
        If strDirection = "left" Then
            enemy.Left = enemy.Left - nTwipsPerMove
        ElseIf strDirection = "right" Then
            enemy.Left = enemy.Left + nTwipsPerMove
        End If
    End If
    If enemy.Left = 0 Then
        If strDirection = "left" Then strDirection = "right"
        enemy.Left = enemy.Left + nTwipsPerMove
    End If

    If enemy.Left + enemy.Width = Me.Width - nTwipsPerMove * 5 Then
        If strDirection = "right" Then strDirection = "left"
        enemy.Left = enemy.Left - nTwipsPerMove
    End If
End Sub
```

`nTwipsPerMove` means how many twips to move in each loop
Timer1.Interval = 10

Answer (score 0):

I'm admitting right now that my VB is rusty.  Been about 10 years since I've used it.  I don't have anyway to test this code, but I think this sample should get you close, or at least get you pointed in the right direction.

```
Private Sub Timer1_Timer()
    Do
       enemy1.Left = enemy1.Left - 5
       If enemy1.Left = < 5 Then
          Do
             enemy1.Right = enemy1.Right + 5
          Loop Until enemy1.Right = > 1000 'or whatever your size is
       End If
    Loop
End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

you can also use 1 variable for its speed, and make it negative when the enemy has to move the other way

```
'1 form with :
'    1 timer : name=Timer1
'    1 picturebox : name=Picture1
Option Explicit

Private msngStep As Single

Private Sub Form_Load()
  Timer1.Interval = 200      'delay in milliseconds between steps
  msngStep = ScaleWidth / 20 'step size, and direction
End Sub

Private Sub Timer1_Timer()
  Dim sngX As Single
  With Picture1 'the enemy
    sngX = .Left + msngStep                              'calculate new position
    If (sngX < 0) Or (sngX > (ScaleWidth - .Width)) Then 'check boundary
      msngStep = msngStep * -1                           'adjust direction
      sngX = sngX + 2 * msngStep                         'keep enemy inside
    End If
    .Left = sngX                                         'move to new position
  End With 'Picture1
End Sub
```

Answer (score -1):

VB (like C#) should have a built in Timer object. Using the timer you should be able to create a event handler that is triggered after a set amount of time, in that function you can move the picture and restart the timer if you still need it.

Comment: I'm sorry but this doesn't help me much. I'm new to the language and I was told that simply just a timer would do the trick.

Comment: Ah my apologize, I am afraid my VB is not quite up to snuff enough to provide an example. I just know that C# and VB implement almost all the same functions. You should be able to find something on MSDN if no one provides an acceptable answer.